# Substituir texto dentro de tag

Tags: lua

Estou tentando substituir dentro de uma tag?
EX:

```
mystr = '<html><head></head><body><p>Aqui meu texto</p></body></html>'
mystr = mystr:gsub('<.+>', '')
print(mystr)
```

Eu gostaria que retornasse:

```
Aqui meu texto
```

Mas não retorna nada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que `'<.+>'` casa todo o string e o `gsub` então remove todo o conteúdo.

Se você quer extrair um texto, use `string.match` e capturas:

```
print(mystr:match('<p>(.-)</p>'))
```

Se você quer substituir o texto, use

```
mystr = mystr:gsub('<p>.-</p>','<p>Eis o novo texto</p>',1)
```

Comment: Com mystr:gsub('<.->', ''), consegui fazer o que estava tentando.

Comment: @GabrielSales, ah, agora entendi: você quer *remover* todas as tags.